# Why doesn't nosetests find anything?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I am switching from python's unittest framework to nosetests, trying to reuse my `unittest.TestCase`s

After `cd`ing into my tests package I started nosetests [as described on their homepage](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html):

```
./test/$ nosetests

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

Why do I need to specify each module to have nose discover its tests like in the following example?

```
./test/$ nosetests test_all.py
.......
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 7 tests in 0.002s

OK
```

Also running the tests one folder above doesn't change anything.

```
./tests/$ cd ..
./$ nosetests

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

Comment: I removed the link to your repo, since questions should generally be self-contained. Feel free to edit in more info if you feel it's necessary. Cheers.

Comment: I leave it [here for people who want to have a look](https://github.com/DFE/night-owl/tree/start_nosetests/test)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I can see in your repo that at least some of the files are executable, so that is at least part of the problem. By default, nose won't collect those: it's trying to avoid running scripts that might do something destructive on import. Try the --exe flag, or removing the executable bit from the test files.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be in the directory above that if you want nose to run all the tests in that package.

Comment: I also tried that without success, see the edited question post

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had following line at the end of the test files:

```
unittest.main()
```

Removing this from all my tests solved my issue.

Comment: Look at the marked solution. It's not saying it explicitly but that what it means.